# openpyxl python3 -- formatting whole rows ellicits strange behavior

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working with pivot-tabled XLSX files and writing a script to parse them out in to a new file per tab.

Since openpyxl doesn't support pivot tables by default I need to do some work to reinsert the pivot 'style' that is lost during copy.

To do this I'm iterating through each row and col, looking for the value `Total` in column 0. Once found, the row should change to be all `bold=True`.

Instead, I receive erratic behavior that sometimes bolds ALL cells after the first `None`. My `print('bolding totals')` message shows that it is evaluating each row/cell correctly. Am I bone-headed and screwing up my indents on the loops, perhaps?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from copy import deepcopy

wb = load_workbook(filename=r'input.xlsx')

# Print 1
sheetlist = wb.get_sheet_names()
print(sheetlist)

for i in range(len(sheetlist)-1):
    dest_filename = r''+sheetlist[i]+'.xlsx'
    new_wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetlist[i])
    new_wb.add_sheet(ws, 0)

    for k in range(0, new_wb.worksheets[0].get_highest_row()):
        print(new_wb.worksheets[0].cell(row=k, column=0).value)
        # ignore empty cells
        if new_wb.worksheets[0].cell(row=k, column=0).value is not None:
            if 'Total' in new_wb.worksheets[0].cell(row=k, column=0).value:
                for j in range(0, new_wb.worksheets[0].get_highest_column()):
                    print('bolding totals, '+str(k), str(j))
                    new_wb.worksheets[0].cell(
                        row=k, column=j).style.font.bold = True
            elif 'Total' not in new_wb.worksheets[0].cell(row=k, column=0).value:
                for j in range(0, new_wb.worksheets[0].get_highest_column()):
                    print('not bolding anything')
                    new_wb.worksheets[0].cell(
                        row=k, column=j).style.font.bold = False

    # remove the blank sheet created in new_wb by openpyxl
    new_wb.remove_sheet(new_wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet'))
    print(new_wb.get_sheet_names())
    new_wb.save(dest_filename)
    break  # set to break after one sheet for testing

print('finished')
```

---

At this point I suspect this is a bug in the openpyxl handling of styles. I ran another very simple edit and got strange behavior.

If we have a simple layout with bold/nonbold cells.
Then we run this simple command to change one cell:

```
>>> new_wb.worksheets[0].cell(row=10,column=0).style.font.bold = False
```

The output changes for the entire column, not the cell alone.

Comment: Hi, bugs in `openpyxl` aren't very shocking to me. I had issues with it previously. It was easier for me to rewrite the entire application to use Excel directly, through driving it via the COM ports, than to fix `openpyxl`. Here's my post with an answer; hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145313/openpyxl-highlighting-multiple-cells-when-one-of-them-is-selected-upon-closing-t

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, even though it's well-written and interesting, because: (a) it has no answers, accepted or otherwise; (b) the links to actual and desired output are dead; (c) the OP has not visited SO in nearly two years; (d) any related openpyxl bug has probably been fixed by now; and (e) it still shows up as an open question even though it's now effectively unanswerable.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I don't remember a bug report on this. Your comment seems to imply that openpyxl is very buggy which I don't think is a fair representation. Of course, working directly with Excel is great if you can. You might also want to look at xlwings for doing this.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311342/should-a-question-be-closed-because-its-apparently-unanswerably-obsolete?cb=1)

Answer (score 7):

Prior to openpyxl 2.0 cell styles were shared between cells: this was a holdover from the implementation using pointers in the source XML: two (or more) cells would both use style "1". Changing this style for one cell would mean changing it for all cells, which sounds like the behaviour being observed here.

Since then, while there have been various changes in implementation, there are no longer any side-effects when changing the style for one cell. An important change is that formatting objects, such as `Font` are directly available and do not have to be wrapped in a style.

There have been some other changes: worksheets cannot be copied between workbooks because they are dependent upon data stored in the parent workbook.

Without the original file it's difficult to be sure but the following code should work with openpyxl >= 2.2

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='input.xlsx', read_only=True)

for sheet in wb.sheetnames:

    dest_filename = '{0}.xlsx'.format(sheet)
    new_wb = Workbook()
    del new_wb["Sheet"]

    ws1 = wb[sheet]
    ws2 = new_wb.create_sheet(sheet)

    for row in ws1:
        ws2.append([c.value for c in row])
        first = row[0]
        if first.data_type == "s" and "Total" in first.value:
            for idx in range(len(row)):
                cell = ws2.cell(row=ws2.max_row, column=idx+1)
                bolded = cell.font.copy(bold=True)
                cell.font = bolded

    new_wb.save(dest_filename)
    print("saving {0}".format(dest_filename))

print('finished')
```